# Difficulty resolving TRUE FALSE question using boolean

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations, boolean-algebra

I'm having some difficulty with a problem I think.

If X = true and Y = true

```
((X AND Y)' AND (X' OR Y') ' ) '
```

I get back true. When I put it in Wolfram Alpha it gave me back false. But I think it may have had a ' by it as well? So I'm not really sure. I'm new to this and hoping for some clarification. My thinking was that:

```
((TRUE AND TRUE) ' AND (TRUE' OR TRUE') ' ) '

((FALSE AND FALSE) AND (FALSE OR FALSE) ' ) '

((FALSE) AND (FALSE) ' ) '

((FALSE) AND (TRUE)) '

((FALSE)) '

((TRUE))
```

Can someone please tell me if this is correct?

Comment: Please provide a link or show us the input for Wolfram Alpha which was evaluated to false.

Comment: I have entered your expression into Wolfram Alpha and it shows me T as the result for X = Y = T: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NOT+%28NOT+%28X+AND+Y%29+AND+NOT+%28NOT+X+OR+NOT+Y%29+%29+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ultimate result TRUE is correct, your calculation is wrong though.

If `'` is the boolean negation which turns true to false and vice versa, you have made a mistake: you did not apply [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

```
(A AND B)' = A' OR B'
(A OR B)' = A' AND B'
```

In particular

```
((FALSE) AND (TRUE))' = FALSE' OR TRUE'
```

which is still `TRUE`.

Complete simplification of the expression is possible without making use of that law though, just by knowing how AND and OR are defined for two given booleans:

```
((TRUE AND TRUE)' AND (TRUE' OR TRUE')')' =
(TRUE' AND (FALSE OR FALSE)')' =
(FALSE AND FALSE')' =
(FALSE AND TRUE)' =
FALSE' =
TRUE
```

We can generalize even further: for any X and Y it is (now using the aforementioned law):

```
((X AND Y)' AND (X' OR Y')')' =
((X AND Y)' AND (X AND Y))' =
(Z' AND Z)' =
FALSE' =
TRUE
```

(with `Z = X AND Y`)

So independent of how you choose X and Y, the result is TRUE.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply.  And yes, the apostrophe is supposed to be negation in the system I was using. I think I'm a little confused, please excuse me. It looks like what I wrote out ultimately was the same as the simplification that you wrote out at the end. Here's what I wrote in the calculator: ((X AND Y)' AND (X' OR Y')')'

The result I got was False ' (X). Does that mean it's actually True and I read it wrong?

Comment: `False ' (X)` seems to be equal to `True (X)` which might have the meaning "true, independent of what X is". If you have problems interpreting your calculator's output, you should refer to its manual or ask a separate question for that. Wolfram Alpha's answer is formatted differently but it says the same: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NOT+%28NOT+%28X+AND+Y%29+AND+NOT+%28NOT+X+OR+NOT+Y%29+%29+